# VS Code whitespace issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, removing-whitespace

[Powershell version and Windows build version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9wWK.png)How to remove the whitespace in the VS Code terminal when running a program?

The Whitespace occurs only when the program is runned twice below the
whitespace the programs output is shown

After running the program for the second time in VS Code the whitespace appears in the terminal:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure "whitespace" is the fact that your viewport has a certain height. A terminal doesn't reallt deal in "whitespace" so much, the programs that write output to it do. They might ask "How many lines are visible" and then use that to align something to your terminal, but in general, a terminal doesn't really know how to align text, so it seems this is intended output from whatever program you are running, or the fact that you haven't made your window smaller.

Comment: If you are talking about the whitespace between `>` and `no`, that whitespace is there by design.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also add your powershell version and exact windows build version number

Comment: @Andreas The white space after the no

Comment: @somethinghere I didn't understand clearly

Comment: @starball updated and the Help: About is 
Version: 1.85.2 (user setup)
Commit: 8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681
Date: 2024-01-18T06:40:10.514Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 26354273
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

Comment: Whitespace in the terminal is always intentional, because it's a dumb terminal. Something is printing that whitespace. The program you are running, for example.